# Collection of Cylinder-Set as a semi ring

Tags: measure-theory, semiring

[This proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662592/show-that-mathfraks-bigcup-n-1-infty-mathfrakz-n-cup-left-emptyset) should show a collection of cylinder set is a Semi-ring. But for the last point they just showed $B\setminus A$  is either $B$ or $\emptyset$. However $B$ or $\emptyset$ is an element of the semiring itself and according to this proof the collection of cylinder set is even a ring. I cant see the point why it should be a semi ring. Could anyone help?

Comment: Do you see that e.g. $\left[a_{1},\dots,a_{N}\right]-\left[a_{1},\dots,a_N,a_{N+1}\right]=\bigcup_{x\in\Gamma-\left\{ a_{N+1}\right\} }\left[a_{1},\dots,a_{N},x\right]$? Since $\Gamma$ is finite this is a disjoint union of cylinder sets.

Comment: Thanks! But why is $[a1,…,aN,x]$ is in the semi ring? Maybe I'm not familiar with the construction of the set. But I thought there is no sets with $[a1,…,aN,x]$ with $x/uneq aN+1$

Comment: I am only saying that for $x$ it is a cylinderset. This gives an example showing that the "difference" of two specific cylinder sets can be written as a finite disjoint union of cylinder sets. So a step in the direction of proving that the cylinder sets form a semiring. It is not a full proof yet, though. But it gives hope and direction.

Comment: Have a look at [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1989237/75923) to the question that you are referring to.

Comment: @drhab Thanks! I just corrected it. But I am still confused about why the $[a_{1}....,a_{M},x_{M+1},...,x_{N}]$  are sets from the Semi ring. I thought for $A_{N}$ the value of $x_{M+1},....,X_{N}$ are fix, namely $a_{M+1}....,a_{N}$. For all sets with other value of $x_{M+1},...,x_{N}$: Why are they in the collection of sets I considering.

Comment: Do you agree that sets like $[a_1,\dots,a_M,x_{M+1},\dots, x_N]$ are cylinder sets? I am not speaking of "elements of semiring" yet, because I am somehow in the middle of a *proof* that these cylinder sets together form indeed a semiring. For that the points 1,2,3 must be proved for the collection of cylinder sets, and in my answer I gave a proof of 3.

Comment: @drhab Ah I see you point. I thought you were done.:-D

Comment: The questioner asked for a proof-verification. He allready gave proofs of 1,2,3, but 3 was wrong. I haven't looked at 2) yet. Maybe I will do that later. Point 1) it trivial. I am going to have some supper now. Cheers.

Comment: @drhab My problem is also 3. 2 is also correct, because it is either empty or B. It is very simple. Only 3, I doubt if it is even true if we only consider one certain setting of $a_{1},...,a_{N}$. Cheers!